# Share save files between computers

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

Ok, so I searched the site and found some semi-relevant topics, but nothing to specifically answer my question.

What I'm trying to do is play Oblivion on two PCs using the same save files. I was thinking that the easiest way would be to cloud share the save files location, but Dropbox for example doesn't allow that. What I can do is simply upload/download the folder every time I switch PC, but I'd like to avoid that. I also considered mapping the save route of the game to a folder inside Dropbox, but as far as I learned it is not possible.

No, I'm not using stream (I know there is a sync option there).

Comment: Unless someone knows of another way, there just isn't an easy way to sync those things with any kind of automation, other than Steam's cloud sync functionality, though as you say, that's not an option for you.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Apparently there is a way, in case you are interested in the solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oddly enough through a little bit of research Dropbox actually can be used to sync saved games between two computers. I haven't tried this method myself since I do not have two computers but this should work for your needs.

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-sync-your-saved-pc-games-between-computers-with-1501078690

Here is a summarized version of the tutorial:

1. Locate you save files folder (usually in User\Documents\My games).
2. Move the folder to Dropbox and delete/rename the original folder.
3. Create a symbolic link ("symlink") from the old folder location to the new on all computers using the following command (from Command prompt):

> mklink /D "C:\Users\Whitson\Documents\My Games\Darksiders"
>   "C:\Users\Whitson\Dropbox\Game Saves\Darksiders"

Replace the first path with the original folder location and the second with the current folder location in Dropbox.

Comment: No problem @KardNails enjoy Oblivion!

Comment: I did this with Minecraft saves a while back; it works pretty well as long as you don't try to play the same save at the same time from multiple machines.

Comment: I found that dropbox tended to lock files as it uploaded any updates, which caused errors in some games - I can't specifically remember which ones though. It works brilliantly in some cases though.